# Outlook Archive Mail Searching

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, pst

I would like to take my old outlook archives and push them to a central location that is full text searchable. I would think something like this is out there some where but I cant seem to find it. If something that could be put on a webserver all the better so I could always have access.

Notes on what I don't want:

- Plugin to Outlook
- Desktop Search
- More steps then uploading pst file

Answer (score 1):

If you have Outlook 2007 on Windows 7, you could just import your archive and have Windows Search search through it full-text

Note: it could be that Outlook 2007 probably is capable of full-text search itself, I just like that with Windows 7 I don't have to open Outlook to find them

Comment: I don't have windows 7 but that is still less then ideal as I would really like to have it be on a webserver so I could do the search from anywhere.

Comment: Sadly Gmail uploading only works with Google Apps, so unless they're still on a server...

Comment: I have a number of old PST archive files some that may still be on a server most are not.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a personal Gmail account to Outlook via IMAP, you can transfer your e-mails over to Gmail. Search on Gmail is lightning fast awesome! If you have a corporate firewall that disallows IMAP, this would not be an option for you.

An alternative is to use Outlook.com via Windows Live Mail. It is basically HotMail that you connect to via HTTP on port 80. This can bypass the corporate firewalls to access e-mail. You can transfer your e-mails to Outlook.com. You can search for e-mails there.

Bonus: You can create an Outlook rule that moves e-mail before a certain date to Outlook.com or Gmail whenever you run the rule.